# Format function parameters in the same line

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode for working with Dart and Flutter. I've enabled the VSCode native formatter for Dart. I've noticed that in functions with a long signature VSCode breaks the line right before the first parameter.

I find this very annoying to read, and after researching for a while I was not able to find a setting to change this.

Any ideas?

Example:

```
void a(
    int b, int c, int d) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: [The Dart formatter is intentionally not configurable](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart_style/wiki/FAQ#why-cant-i-configure-it) so that code is always formatted consistently.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a long formal argument list, the convention is to add a comma after the `int d` to allow the formatter to put them in a vertical list.

Comment: I was wondering why the formatting would format everything nicely in the flutter screen files and not in my object creation but I was indeed just missing the comma after the last parameter. This was driving me nuts, thanks :D